# What is the word which means 'giving a speech with no preparation/practice'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am not able to recall it. It has been bothering since so many months but I am absolutely clueless.

Solved: Yes, 'Extemporize' was the word. Thank you.

Comment: ***impromptu***

Comment: [Extemporize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extemporize)?

Comment: "Off the cuff" is a common idiom.

Answer (score 1):

Each time I had to do that, I ***improvised***.